# PHPMailer DKIM signature_incorrect

Tags: phpmailer, dkim

I'm trying to setup DKIM for my PHP emails, but when I send email to isnotspam.com, it is saying:

```
X_DKIM_Status: fail (signature_incorrect)
```

I generated a public/private rsa key pair with ssh-keygen with no password. I've put the private key on my server, and the public key into my DNS records:

```
TXT default._domainkey  v=DKIM1;t=s;p=XXXXXXXXX
```

I'm using PHPMailer to send the code on a GoDaddy shared server. The PHP version is out of date, so I have to use version 5.2 of PHPMailer:

```
// Start of PHP code
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress($email_address, "");

// Setup DKIM
$mail->DKIM_domain = "letmein.org";
$mail->DKIM_private = $key_path;
$mail->DKIM_selector = "default";
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = "";
$mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;

// Send the email
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $html;
$mail->AltBody = "Plain text";
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->send();
```

The email is sending fine, but failing the DKIM checks. I've tried replacing the existing keys with new ones generated using a website specifically for DKIM keys (also checked the new public key in the DNS records were being picked up).

The original email:

```
From mark@letmein.org Sun Dec 24 16:05:48 2017
Return-path: <mark@letmein.org>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on
localhost.localdomain
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Level: ****
X-Spam-Report: 
* -0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, no
* trust
* [188.121.43.193 listed in list.dnswl.org]
* 3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* -0.0 RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H3 RBL: Good reputation (+3)
* [188.121.43.193 listed in wl.mailspike.net]
* -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
* 0.2 BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* 0.1 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
* 0.8 MPART_ALT_DIFF BODY: HTML and text parts are different
* -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
* domain
* 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
* valid
* -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
* -0.0 RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_WL Mailspike good senders
X-Spam-Status: Yes, hits=4.5 required=-20.0 tests=BAYES_99,BAYES_999,
DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_MESSAGE,MPART_ALT_DIFF,
RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H3,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_WL,SPF_PASS autolearn=no
autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
Envelope-to: ins-xqvykojr@isnotspam.com
Delivery-date: Sun, 24 Dec 2017 16:05:48 +0000
Received: from n1nlsmtp03.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net ([188.121.43.193])
by localhost.localdomain with esmtp (Exim 4.84_2)
(envelope-from <mark@letmein.org>)
id 1eT8mZ-000CeP-TQ
for ins-xqvykojr@isnotspam.com; Sun, 24 Dec 2017 16:05:48 +0000
Received: from n1plcpnl0106.prod.ams1.secureserver.net ([188.121.57.40])
by : HOSTING RELAY : with SMTP
id T8lWeadPYo71OT8lWeAKc1; Sun, 24 Dec 2017 09:04:42 -0700
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=letmein.org
; s=default; h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID
:Subject:From:To:Date:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-ID:Content-Description:
Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:
In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe:
List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
bh=okJ3Yvq2jDr8JtULj6ItIiWaJF2OOV2IKKV7bcEXKD8=; b=FwSTkJ4lmwddF4ql5xz6ZlDxAm
DFRNxX7DjFrJXgcrJAwmk+GFR6vuj9yIeU0Sv7sZx3CTPdTVPNcmXYUrEEbeOEULCg6Gtvq5Iiocy
TPhVuPoz9vKlp59oIY20iIGBGb4Exa46GZJl7myIme8p8zAqs2JvDoBYxjCihbBxY79Ccebr+7kKS
Rhtx8eNsiZgXfNRAkVYeRHwGS0RgFVSt+7OdBJgTKGrmFRYgAwNMsngl/kicSgdpR6l1aZCKiTLqz
8gVeXXZ3CaHgupEc11m3m4y2B1igYiLGB1OBsbYI0oxgoOMDpWz2cGUFqJWOYzih4nlwMchZsPydT
qfXbWL+Q==;
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (port=40914 helo=www.letmein.org)
by n1plcpnl0106.prod.ams1.secureserver.net with esmtpsa (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
(Exim 4.89)
(envelope-from <mark@letmein.org>)
id 1eT8lW-001NfM-PR
for ins-xqvykojr@isnotspam.com; Sun, 24 Dec 2017 09:04:42 -0700
Date: Sun, 24 Dec 2017 16:04:37 +0000
To: ins-xqvykojr@isnotspam.com
From: Mark McCorrie <mark@letmein.org>
Subject: Test Email
Message-ID: <5335fe27777b3c14ed79690ca2bb1584@www.letmein.org>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.26 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="b1_5335fe27777b3c14ed79690ca2bb1584"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; l=394; s=default;
t=1514131477; c=relaxed/simple;
h=From:To:Date:Subject;
d=letmein.org; i=mark@letmein.org;
z=From:=20Mark=20McCorrie=20<mark@letmein.org>
|To:=20ins-xqvykojr@isnotspam.com
|Date:=20Sun,=2024=20Dec=202017=2016:04:37=20+0000
|Subject:=20Test=20Email;
bh=okJ3Yvq2jDr8JtULj6ItIiWaJF2OOV2IKKV7bcEXKD8=;
b=DdTZwAhwG5veqdzYalqHZemZxrI8jP3nN60bYQ3QLB1SizMeXJPY3CDASb0jD0p7jvPJ7S0EWVRGUd4OYf4G9JOtuPJ5gyXcIaLskHaR1C2UkK7VEsdULpTuBOyi7NNNykKj0Bb/Phf4E9a5KS1fTQ/zeRHcUuaTlCqUqmKxsfQ=
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - n1plcpnl0106.prod.ams1.secureserver.net
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - isnotspam.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - letmein.org
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: n1plcpnl0106.prod.ams1.secureserver.net: authenticated_id: mark@letmein.org
X-Authenticated-Sender: n1plcpnl0106.prod.ams1.secureserver.net: mark@letmein.org
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: 
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4wfPwC1Xxnn9g6j5zbro5YKM7KLqmVfWh0KVY65g/CeDYX+99xryWgrTFmrIqXyjax2lhli+BPTzUFMcNEi0jmyvPoh7bb5eN1483k57SPVgGzVF736hje
JeW4+Womlh7Mp70ZEMTbXH9nJ5WO+R98qk7fuq1gLqB6PO1Y4OZ4NW8e52fTMhNAsNPTqEjdZs56FumTu5tMlbJRhCDFtwc51/s=
X-DKIM-Status: fail (signature_incorrect)
X-DKIM-Status: pass (mark@letmein.org)
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--b1_5335fe27777b3c14ed79690ca2bb1584
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Plain text


--b1_5335fe27777b3c14ed79690ca2bb1584
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<html><body>
<p>Hi Mark,</p>
<p>This is a test email to see if you are using DKIM correctly.</p></body></html>



--b1_5335fe27777b3c14ed79690ca2bb1584--
```

Any ideas?

P.s. I've been fiddling around with keys and the current DNS record might not align with the original email above.

Comment: Does GoDaddy really only provide PHP versions older than 5.5 (the minimum PHPMailer 6.0 needs)? If so, they’re worse than I thought. In the current master branch of PHPMailer there are some DKIM fixes, but they are not in 5.2.

Comment: Interesting. I thought GoDaddy controlled the PHP version. Updated to PHP7.1, got the latest PHPMailer, and did a lot of messing around with the keys and DNS record. It seems that of the two signatures, the body is passing, but the header is failing. This suggests the keys are setup correctly now if they weren't before. Perhaps a bug in PHPMailer?

Comment: Make sure you use the dev-master version to confirm that. You shouldn't have two DKIM signatures like this - it looks like your mail server is adding a second one, and I'd recommend letting it do that rather than using PHPMailer for that - it will be faster.

Comment: It looks like GoDaddy add their own, but they stopped giving you a public key a couple of years ago, but still add a DKIM signature.